# Is there a programmatic way to switch Windows from English to Spanish?

Tags: language

From what I've read, the Language Bar appears to be solely for switching the keyboard language.

To change the language used by Windows GUI and the browser (Chrome in my case), the only method I've found is to go to Settings > Time & Language > Language > Preferred Language, switch the default from English to Spanish, sign out, and then upon signing in everything will be in Spanish as expected.

Is there another way to toggle a system between English and Spanish other than using Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Too many components need to reload in order to affect the system language, so signing out is always required. If you don't, some programs or settings may show one language while another may show the other.

I'm also not familiar with any other way to change the system language other than going through the Settings or Control Panel, though I believe Microsoft removed the Control Panel option. Maybe through [the Windows 10 Godmode](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-god-mode-windows-10) hack.

## Old answer before OP edited the question:

The language bar allows you to both switch to a different keyboard language temporarily and be used as an indication what the current selected language is, in case you use the hotkeys (hold <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> + press once <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>, (hold <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + press once <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> or <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

Windows keeps track of the selected language per program, so if you switch to another program, the icon will tell you it changed back to the default.

Comment: Right, the Language Bar in the Taskbar is for the keyboard. But to make Windows show all of its text in Spanish one must go through Settings, sign-off, etc. I'm asking if there's an alternative to the latter, like maybe using the command line, Powershell, or the Registry.

Comment: Do you realize, that by editing your question, you invalidated a perfectly good answer? People may now vote my answer down because it is no longer correct. Please don't edit your question and make it means something else if you appear to have made an error in asking the proper question. Instead, you should accept the answer and ask a new question.